# Expanding TR regardless of its TH in a table

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

I have a dataset that has an optional last TD that is required to have a TH but regardless of that, I need the TRs to expand to show the background-color (fill it in).

Here's a fiddle showing my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/xkwCp/1/

I need the last three rows (the second tbody) to expand (organically or by JS). But it needs to read that there is no 3rd TD, and expand it as needed regardless of that TD, and without adding dummy TDs because it'll be generated dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an answer in jQuery, not CSS:

If you need only for a scenario where the last tbody is incomplete, you can use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xkwCp/5/)

If you need something more generic, with tbodies (complete or incomplete) piled with any order  you can use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xkwCp/7/)

Comment: That's a good solution, but how would it perform with a large set?

Comment: @TalasanNicholson It depends. I supposed that the last body was the body with rows without complete columns. How would be the scenario in a large set? The first tbody complete and n tbodys incompletes?

Comment: Testing it out, I did this: http://jsfiddle.net/sTwFZ/1/ but running comparisons, yours is faster. Can you make it so that the script would be generic, rather than based on the last tbody? Since there'll be a lot of tbodies.

Comment: @TalasanNicholson but I need more information: there are a lot of tbodies, but: always the first tbody is complete? or are many tbodies incompletes and tbodies completes piled without any order?

Comment: It's just random, basically. Sometimes the first tbody will be complete, or incomplete, and the second the same way.

Comment: Cool! What makes yours perform better than using .find(), .children() etc?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4738/discussion-between-galled-and-talasan-nicholson)

Answer (score 1):

You need to count the empty rows, then use `rowspan` on the last column. You cannot do this with CSS.